# Azure event grid to multiply listeners

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventgrid

I have a WPF application used by up to 10 users, which needs to communicate with Azure Functions but also send events between applications.

For this I have created a Event Grid Topic in Azure and a Hybrid Connection. This makes it possible for me to publish an event from outside Azure and consume it as well all done i C#. However even though there are multiply applications open and listening to the event only one application receives the Event.

Is it possible to use the same Hybrid Connection for multiply applications and all of them receives the Event? Or are there another way of making this happen using Azure? I don't know in advance how many applications are open and will need the Event.

Comment: Hybrid Connection doesn't support a multicasting, so in your scenario the event message is delivered only to one application in the balanced manner. I do recommend for your case to use a Azure SignalR Service (Azure Web PubSub) for multicasting an event message to all connected applications in the loosely decoupled manner.

Comment: Thanks Roman, that solved my problem. With further research I discovered that SignalR can be used in combination with Azure Event grid : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64764117/azure-event-grid-subscription-to-console-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echoing to [Roman Kiss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8084828/roman-kiss), posting your suggestion as answer to this to help the other community members.

Hybrid Connection doesn't support a multicasting, so in your scenario the event message is delivered only to one application in the balanced manner. I do recommend for your case to use a Azure SignalR Service (Azure Web PubSub) for multicasting an event message to all connected applications in the loosely decoupled manner.